# Angular - inconsistent countdown with angular material progressbar

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I have a countdown timer:

```js
interval;
timeJump: number = 10;
timeLength: number = 5;
timerLeft: number = this.timeLength;

startTimer() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.timerLeft - this.timeJump / 1000 <= 0) {
        this.timerLeft = 0;
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        return;
        setTimeout(() => this.finishedTimer(), 500);
      } else {
        this.timerLeft -= this.timeJump / 1000;

      }
    }, this.timeJump);
}
```

I am calling the startTimer() function in ngOnInit(), and it is running.

In the html template I have a progress bar:

```html
<div class="progress-wrapper" style="height: 4%;">
      <mat-progress-bar id="timer" mode="determinate" value="{{(timerLeft/timeLength) * 100}}"
                        style="height: 100%;"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

When the timer reaches the end, about the last 10%, it goes down in value a lot quicker than it should.
[image: Progress bar demonstration]

Can you help me fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!
The problem was I was using too short of an interval. The progress bar couldn't keep up with the speed. Set the interval to whatever you want, but always round the value you put in the value of the progress bar to a whole number, like this:

```
 timeLeft | number : '1.0-0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a problem? Work perfect for me!
(except for `setTimeout(() => this.finishedTimer(), 500);` after `return;` never be used)

But, you can use RxJs for that!

HTML

```
<mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progressbarValue"></mat-progress-bar>
```

TS

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
...
progressbarValue = 100;
curSec: number = 0;

startTimer(seconds: number) {
    const time = seconds;
    const timer$ = interval(1000);

    const sub = timer$.subscribe((sec) => {
      this.progressbarValue = 100 - sec * 100 / seconds;
      this.curSec = sec;

      if (this.curSec === seconds) {
        sub.unsubscribe();
      }
    });
}
```

And call startTime method with progress bar timeout.

```
startTimer(120) // 120 seconds
```

References: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-progress-bar-decrease

Comment: Do you know why my solution didn't work? I will try yours and if it works I will accept it

Comment: It doesn't work, the same thing happens. At the last bit it goes a lot more quickly. I am using 10 milliseconds as the interval for smoothness

Comment: For clarity, turn `time Left / time Length) * 100` into a variable and print. So you will know when the value is zero (probably, on the penultimate call of the timer method). Btw, for smoothness, the percentage value needs to use the timeout in the calculation.